# Create Derived object given a base Object

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a base class which has a `__init__` that takes two parameters. I want to create a derived class object, given that I have a base class object.
I want to do the following,

```
a_obj = A(10, 'f') 
## given that I have a_obj, create b_obj
b_obj = B(a_obj)
```

and get a result such that

```
type(b_obj) => B

print(b_obj.age) => 10
print(b_obj.sex) => "f"
```

I tried the following, where the `__new__` of B would call A's `__new__` and ask it to create an object of type B(an empty object). But at this point I dont know how to set B to have all the functionalities of A.

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, age, sex):
    self.age = age
    self.sex = sex

class B(A):
  def __new__(cls, a_obj):
    a_class = a_obj.__class__
    b_obj = a_class.__new__(cls)
    a_class.__init__(b_obj, a_obj) #doesnt work since A's init takes 2 params
```

Is there a better way than to typecast the given A's object to B?
( i.e `a_obj.__classs__ = b_obj` )

**Edit:**
  B is a dynamically created class(using type). So B wouldnt know beforehand what are the parameters that A's `__init__` would take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way, by passing `a`'s attributes in a call to [super](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, age, sex):
      self.age = age
      self.sex = sex

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a):
         """a is an instance of A"""
         super().__init__(a.age, a.sex)
```

---

In answer to "what if B was a dynamically generated class? B doesnt know what A's params are", that is a lot harder, and requires some true python hacking.

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.__dict__.update(a.__dict__)
```

I do not endorse doing this. It is bad coding practise and possibly error prone.

Comment: Not hard at all actually and does not require any hack - just use `*args` and `**kwargs` like you would for a decorator or any generic callable.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, pass `a_object.age` and `a_object.sex` to the parent constructor.

```
class A(object):
  def __init_(self, age, sex):
    self.age = age
    self.sex = sex

class B(A):
  def __init__(self, a):
      super(B, self).__init__(a.age, a.sex)
```

Now note that one usually expects subclasses to be compatible with their parents, which is not the case here.

Edit: to answer the additional question "what if B is dynamically generated and doesn't know  beforehand what are the parameters that A's **init** would take", the canonical solution is to use varargs and keyword args:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(B, self).__init__(*args, **kawargs)
```

Comment: @FHTMitchell chill out - your answer wasn't posted when I started writing mine, I only saw it after posting (else I wouldn't have bothered answering).

Comment: Sorry. I'm chill +1

Comment: @FHTMitchell and bruno, what if B was a dynamically generated class? B doesnt know what A's params are.

Comment: @user2626431 use `*args` and `**kwargs`, cf my edited answer.

Comment: Your edit doesn't answer the question, I think: the `__init__` of B is supposed to take only one parameter, and instance of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with the example it's not clear whether inheritance will be used for any purpose other than a properties access.
If getting all the object fields is only thing you want, I guess, it's not necessary to use inheritance.

Since every object in python has [**dict**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) property, you can just copy it:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, age, sex):
        self.age = age
        self.sex = sex

class B:
    def __init__(self, a_obj):
        self.__dict__ = a_obj.__dict__.copy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a_obj = A(10, "f")
    b_obj = B(a_obj)

    print(type(b_obj)) # B

    # Works as expected.
    print(b_obj.age)
    print(b_obj.sex)
```

Although provided example will work as-well with inheritance, but in that case I'd hardly suggest to use parent constructor as described above.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe using [**getattr**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__), within class B,

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, a_object):
        self._a = a_object

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self._a, item)
```

So if `b_obj` doesn't have an `age` attribute, it will refer to the `age` within `a_object`.

Comment: The OP wants `B` to derive from `A`.